# How to show records from three tables without foreach

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have problem how to make query to join records from 3 tables and print results on screen. I made solution but isn't good for speed and I have been seeking for better solution. My tables are:

<kbd>test table</kbd>

```
id_test
testName
```

<kbd>question table</kbd>

```
id_quest
id_test
question
```

<kbd>answer table</kbd>

```
id_answer
id_quest
answer
```

Every test has 7 questions and every question has 10 answers.

How to write database query without foreach to list this records on screen?

I made solution like this:

```
    $this->db->select('id_test,testName,description,time,type,sum');
    $this->db->where('id_test',$idTest);
    $query['test'] = $this->db->get('tests')->result()[0];

    $this->db->select('id_quest,inquiry');
    $this->db->where('id_test',$idTest);
    $query['questions'] = $this->db->get('questions')->result();

    $i=0;
    foreach ($query['questions'] as $question) {
        $this->db->select('id_answer,response,value');
        $this->db->where('id_quest',$question->id_quest);
        $query['questions'][$i]->answer = $this->db->get('answer')->result();
        $i++;
    }
    return $query;
```

Comment: either you use a loop, or you write out every single line of whatever-was-in-the-loop for what your queries return.

Comment: so it's not possible to write on another way that I already wrote?

Comment: Yes you can use while, but a loop is obligatory.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a more complex query like this so that you only have to hit the database once:

```
SELECT 
t.id_test, t.testName, t.description, t.time, t.type, t.sum,
q.id_quest, q.inquiry,
a.id_answer, a.response, a.value
FROM tests AS t
LEFT JOIN questions AS q ON q.id_test = t.id_test
LEFT JOIN answers AS a ON a.id_quest = q.id_quest
WHERE t.id_test = $idTest;
```

Then your code will look something like this:

```
<?php
// your database info here
$db_host = '';
$db_user = '';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = '';

$con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);
if($con->connect_error)
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());

$query = "SELECT 
t.id_test, t.testName, t.description, t.time, t.type, t.sum,
q.id_quest, q.inquiry,
a.id_answer, a.response, a.value
FROM tests AS t
LEFT JOIN questions AS q ON q.id_test = t.id_test
LEFT JOIN answers AS a ON a.id_quest = q.id_quest
WHERE t.id_test = ?";

if (!$stmt = $con->prepare($query))
    die('Prepare Error: ' . $con->error);

$idTest = 2;
if (!$stmt->bind_param('i', $idTest))
    die('Bind Parameters Error ' . $stmt->error);

if (!$stmt->execute())
    die('Select Query Error ' . $stmt->error);

while ($stmt->fetch())
{
// get each resulting answer row, complete with associated question id and test id
}
$stmt->close();
$con->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I get of your question you're looking to join the tables. I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT test_table.test_name,
       qestion_table.question, 
       answer_table.answers 
FROM test_table
INNER JOIN questions_table 
on questions_table.id_test = test_table.id_test
INNER JOIN answers_table
ON answers_table.id_quest = questions_table.id_quest
WHERE test_table.id_test = ?
```

This should return the entire result set as one object rather than having to query the db several times.

Comment: I would also sort the ouput by test_name, question, answers if the results are to be processed as a simple array or output directly to maintain the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

I would totally look into using 'where_in' instead of throwing tons of queries at you database.

i.e..

```
//...

$this->db->select('id_quest,inquiry'); 
$this->db->where('id_test',$idTest);
$query['questions'] = $this->db->get('questions')->result();

$questionIds = array();

foreach($query['questions'] as $question)
     $questionIds[] = $question->id_quest;

$this->db->select('id_answer,response,value');
$this->db->where_in('id_quest', $questionIds);
$answers = $this->db->get('answer')->result();

$i=0; // <<< Idk what the main purpose of this is, 
      //     but you do know you can simply use '[]' appending to an array, right?
foreach ($answers as $answer) {
    $query['questions'][$i]->answer = $answer;
    $i++;
}
```

Also if performance is still a major issue. Look into caching. CodeIgniter supports this very well.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/caching.html

P.S Also look into the join command in CI.
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Comment: If performance is an issue, do not use where_in - this forces a specific exection path on the db optimizer. If you have found this to speed up your queries then you probably haven't been doing your housekeeping.